# Parsing big hexadecimal numbers in Java

Tags: java, string, numbers

I'm trying to parse into `int` a `String` which is hexadecimal number in my code (FF00FF00, for example) using `Integer.parseInt(String string, int radix)`, but always get `NumberFormatException`. If I parse the number without last two numbers (FF00FF) it works well.

Is there any method to parse such big numbers in Java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If Integer is too small, use [`Long`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html):

```
Long.parseLong(string, 16)
```

If Long is still too small, use [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
new BigInteger(string, 16)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about existence of this class. I have very little experience in Java. I understand, I need a time :-). Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @teoREtik the difference is: Integer and Long are Object wrappers around primitive types. BigInteger and BigDecimal are Object-based solutions which means the arithmetic is probably slightly less efficient (does anybody have numbers about that?) but they can hold arbitrarily big numbers, only limited by the memory you have in your machine, whereas Integer, Long, Float etc are limited by what the corresponsing primitive type can hold.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Long.parseLong(x, 16)` BigInteger is overkill for a 32-bit value.

If you expect this value to be an int value you can cast the result.

```
int x = (int) Long.parseLong("FF00FF00", 16);
```

Comment: true, I hadn't realized that the OP had actually listed the failing strings

Comment: @teoREtik the Original Poster, i.e. you :-)